# Why are test images from my Fujifilm X100F softer than I expect?

Tags: image-quality, sharpness

I just got a copy of the X100F, and I was really excited to play around with it.  But as I've taken a handful of pictures in various settings, I've noticed that the sharpness of the images were not what I would expect from a $1300 camera (and from Fuji glass no less!).  So, I ran the sharpness experiment, taping a $2 bill to a vertical surface and shot at all the fstops (at 200 iso, on a tripod, and focused on the center at ~3 feet back).  To my dismay, the images were just lame in terms of sharpness.

I am posting my comparison image at f2 (worst) and f5.6 (sharpest - but still crappy) at 100% crop.  Would you go through all the hassle of sending back your copy with these results?  Remember that this is the very best of conditions and this is the best it will ever produce.  When hand held, it just gets worse from here.

[image]

I am also attaching someone else's test image(s), I was expecting to have sharpnesses similar (but not exact) to [this](https://cdn.alikgriffin.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/X100F_DiffractionChart.jpg).  But, alas, that is not the case with my copy.

Should I try for another copy?

Comment: I had an X100S with the older sensor, but it created some of my sharpest images. I'd suggest trying a second copy if you still can...

Comment: What percentage of the frame does this crop represent?

Comment: @mattdm - I redid my sharpness test.  You should be able to see the percentage in my second run.

Comment: How do you know it's the UV filter and not an issue of AF accuracy? Have you ensured the target is perpendicular to the lens (DoF differences between f/2 and f/5.6 could account for a softer f/2 crop of an OOF area)? Are you using manual focus w/magnification or AF?

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I tried this again.  But this time I didn't use my tripod, I placed it on my counter-top (it didn't budge one bit when I shot the images, much easier to guarantee this).  But I also removed my UV filter, which I believe was also making my images blurry.

Look at these new images, these **in my opinion are acceptable**.  *Do you agree?*

**Original image:**
[image]

**100% crop at f2 and f5.6:**
[image]

Comment: Yeah, I guess we can file this one as another case of “UV filters: not worth it"

Comment: What mattdm said. Obviously the UV filter. What brand do you use here? In any cas you might want to get a lens hood for protection instead.
If it's not the UV filter you have a defective X100F obviously. Mine is extremely sharp.